Access via indirect Oracle DB Link
We have 3 Oracle 19c sites. To keep it simple, call them SiteA, SiteB, and SiteC. The instance at SiteB has a DB Link to SiteA; and the instance at SiteC has a DBLink to SiteB. However, there is no dblink from SiteC to SiteA. Is there a way to access the instance at SiteA from the instance at SiteC directly, without creating another DB Link ?
I tried using 2 @'s to reference the 2 DB Links, but it is obviously not the correct syntax:
eg. table@site_a@site_b

In general, no you can't do that in the way you have described. The only way would be to create intermediate views in site_b that point through the second dblink to site_a.
In site_b:
create view table_a as select * from table@site_a;

Then in site_c:
select * from table_a@site_b;

This approach is NOT recommended, as you'll be creating workload in all three instances with each query, doubling your network latency, and you'll need to maintain new database objects in site_b to mirror those in site_a. There may be security implications as well. You'd be better off in most respects creating a direct dblink.

I would say "yes you can do that, but..."

No you cannot add 2 @'s, the better approach is to create a direct DBlink from SiteC to SiteA. You can indirectly access SiteC to SiteA by creating views in SiteB referencing objects in SiteA  and using it in SiteC, but that will be little messy.

I modified my response to qualify that it can't be done as described by the OP. DB links can't be chained in a single command.

The question was Is there a way to access the instance at SiteA from the instance at SiteC directly, without creating another DB Link?, and the answer would be yes, in the way you explained (use a view or synonym). Sorry, didn't mean to be overly pedantic.
